# How to make automated post writer, without Selenium

Tags: selenium, post, automation, request

I'm building a news-bot. So I should automatically post articles on my company's web-page. Maybe I can make it automated easily with Selenium, but I feel Selenium produces so many random errors.
So I wonder if I can post articles in another way.

For example, can I use the 'request - post' function to post articles? Or should I just access directly to the Database to which the web-page is referring, by the JavaScript DOM language?

I just want to know which keyword should I dig into.

Comment: Yes, you want requests to POST to your website. Are you using wordpress? Some other framwork for your company website?

Comment: @DMart Company uses other framework, had built for itself.

Comment: Ok, but do you know the way to send a POST request to create a new posting?

Comment: @DMart That's what I'm now starting to study...  So can I write articles by sending a POST request, though the company don't use wordpress or dont' have API system?

Comment: 1. Check in webpage documentation how messages should be build. 
2. Use python + requests framework and write expected script.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, i dont think selenium produces random errors lol, if you have an errror you cant fix, either google or ask here, they are mostly easy to fix. Second of all you could use the element.send_keys() function from selenium